# How to access table's schema from Generic UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I have a table with columns that can have two possible data variants 1 or 0 as a field value. As in example bellow:

```
question    |John   |Ann    |Bob    |Melisa
first       |1      |0      |1      |0
second      |0      |0      |1      |0
third       |1      |1      |1      |0
fourth      |1      |0      |1      |1
```

As a result, I want to have a view which will take user-specified hive variable like: `set name = "Ann"` and produce, for a column which equals variable, 'agreed' or 'disagreed' as a result. And the output from view should look like:

```
question    |Ann    
first       |disagreed      
second      |disagreed      
third       |agreed 
fought      |disagreed
```

So, I know that I can access Hive variables through GenericUDF's configure method like:

```
public void configure(MapredContext mapredContext) {
  String name = mapredContext.getJobConf().get("name");
}
```

Currently, I am passing all field to GenericUDf as an array (because the number of columns in a table can increase).

```
SELECT question, GenericUDF(array(*));
```

Is there an approach how to access a table schema from GenericUDF or maybe it's possible to pass it to a GUDF as a parameter?